# do_shortcode is outputting a string

Tags: plugins

I'm trying to display a responsive navigation bar. I currently have it outputting through the use of the plugin, but I'm working on the responsiveness, and so it'd help to embed the navigation bar inside of my header; rather than negative margin to move it up to my header (this ruins responsiveness). I'm using `<?php echo do_shortcode('[responsive-menu]');?>` but when I view it on the webpage it just echos the string `[responsive-menu]`

Comment: Have you tried adding the menu name to see if that changes anything? `<?php echo do_shortcode( '[responsive-menu menu="menu-name"]' ); ?>`

Comment: What is the menu's name under Appearance > Menus? If it exists there, not sure how your plugin works.

Comment: I ask because instead of echoing you can try: `<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'responsive-menu' )); ?>` but only if the menu name is "responsive-menu"

Comment: Where/when is the shortcode defined?